# How to know when Webserver completely sent data and wait to receive new request?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, networking

I'm doing my computer network homework. My teacher asked me to write a proxy server (it supports HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1).

In my source code, I create a socket manager to manage connections. Since having a new connection, I create a socket client and pass it into the thread (call it thread1). The socket manager will continue listening. And in the thread I've created I do something such as: getting IP, port, method... and then create a new socket to connect to the web server.

When connected successfully I send a request to webserver and create a thread (thread2) to receive data from server to proxy -> client. Thread2 inside thread1, thread1 will receive request from client and send to proxy -> server. I know that chrome uses persistent with non-pipeline http. But when I check the order of sending requests and receiving responses, I see that it's pipelined. Some requests are subsequently sent before client receives response. Can you explain that problem?

To solve it, I decided not to create thread2. Instead, I use a While loop in thread1. Client will receive until Server completely sent response (only 1 response) then sending new request without closing connection. But I don't know how to know when the server completely sent its data. I think it's done when length of received data == 0, but the server hasn't closed connection.
Can you give me a solution?
Thanks.

```
//thread1: call thread2 and send request to Proxy -> Server
CWinThread *p = AfxBeginThread((AFX_THREADPROC)proxyToServer, (LPVOID)P);

    //up stream, Client -> Proxy -> Server
    while (P->isClientClose == FALSE && P->isServerClose == FALSE){
        memset(DataTemp, 0, 10001);
        Length = recv(*Client, DataTemp, 10000, 0);
        if (Length <= 0){
            break;
        }
        Length = send(*Server, DataTemp, Length, 0);
        if (Length <= 0){
            break;
        }
    }
    if (P->isClientClose == FALSE){
        P->isClientClose = TRUE;
        closesocket(*Client);
    }
    if (P->isServerClose == FALSE){
        P->isServerClose = TRUE;
        closesocket(*Server);
    }
//thread2, send data from Server -> Proxy -> Client
DWORD WINAPI proxyToServer(LPVOID* pParam){
    Param *P = (Param*)pParam;
    char *Data = new char[10001];
    while (P->isClientClose == FALSE && P->isServerClose == FALSE){
        memset(Data, 0, 10001);
        int length = recv(*(P->SERVER), Data, 10000, 0);
        if (length <= 0) 
            break;
        length = send(*(P->CLIENT), Data, length, 0);
        if (length <= 0) 
            break;
    }
    if (P->isClientClose == FALSE){
        P->isClientClose = TRUE;
        closesocket(*(P->CLIENT));
    }
    if (P->isServerClose == FALSE){
        P->isServerClose = TRUE;
        closesocket(*(P->SERVER));
    }
    delete[]Data;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: "*when I check the order of sending requests and receiving responses, I see that it's pipeline*" - there is no problem with that. HTTP clients are allowed to pipeline their requests. They just have to be sure to process responses in the same order that the requests were sent. See [RFC 2616 Section 8.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-8.1). "*I don't know how to know when Server completely send data*" - you would have to implement the HTTP protocol (which your code does not) and actually parse the responses. See [RFC 2616 Section 4.4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-4.4)

Comment: thanks @RemyLebeau, it's very helpful to me.
By the way, i have new problem in cache :))))
It's nice when you can see and help :D
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56508300/how-to-store-the-http-response-and-send-to-browser