# How to store the http response and send to browser?

Tags: c++, sockets, http, encoding, httpresponse

I'm doing an exercise about Proxy Server.
I have some problems when caching in Proxy Server.
The following source code is used when the server sends a response to proxy and proxy forward it to the client. It's fine.

```cpp
//that code is ok
fstream File;
while (P->isClientClose == FALSE && P->isServerClose == FALSE){
    memset(Data, 0, 1024);
    int length = recv(*(P->SERVER), Data, sizeof(Data), 0);
    if (length <= 0)
        break;
    length = send(*(P->CLIENT), Data, length, 0);
    if (length <= 0)
        break;
}
```

But when I try to write HTTP response to a file and then read all characters from file to send to the client, I have a problem.
browser said: ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

I'm testing how does proxy cache work, but I can't understand where is error. 
Even when i create a string Temp(Data), and use send(*(P->CLIENT), Temp.c_str(), length, 0), client still said that error.
Please help me. :D

```cpp
//that code is error
fstream File;
while (P->isClientClose == FALSE && P->isServerClose == FALSE){
    memset(Data, 0, 1024);
    int length = recv(*(P->SERVER), Data, sizeof(Data), 0);
    if (length <= 0)
        break;

    File.open("test.dat", ios::out|ios::binary);
    File << Data;
    File.close();
    File.open("test.dat", ios::in|ios::ate|ios::binary);
    ifstream::pos_type pos = File.tellg();
    int size = pos;
    cout << "size: " << size << endl;
    char *pChars = new char[size+1]{};
    File.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    File.read(pChars, size);
    File.close();   
    length = send(*(P->CLIENT), pChars, length, 0);
    delete[]pChars;
    if (length <= 0)
        break;
}
```

Comment: `File << Data;` should not be used to write binary data, also you ignore actual amount of data received. `memset(Data, 0, 1024);` uses some magic number.

Comment: can you explain more about data received? length is number of received bytes, and i think it's ok. memset is try to set Data to null array char. (before, i declare char* Data=new char[1024]

Comment: Then you have an error when passing `sizeof(Data)`. Amount of bytes received may be less than amount of bytes requested.

Comment: oh @VTT, i understood the problem, thanks guy! :D

Comment: btw, i think `sizeof(Data)` is maximum bytes i can receive. i think it's not issue when i receive less than it.

Comment: the problem is that `sizeof(Data)` yields the size of the pointer, not the size of the buffer it points to

Comment: oh sorry bro, i declare `char Data[1024]`, not `new char`. :3 i remember wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A few things stick out.

Update: It looks like you have the communications sorted, so I removed that dribble.

But I think your issue is in the line:
     File << Data;

VTT is correct by pointing out that File << Data doesn't write the full contents of our pointer Data into the file.  The << operator doesn't know the length of the data you want to write. Also, it doesn't appear that the << operator has a char * overload.  See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/

I assume Data is a char * .

Instead of File << Data, try:

```
 File.write( Data, length);
```

And then read it back and write it to the client....